# Scroll stuttering while using coordinator layout with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm having a problem with `Coordinatorlayout` and `ViewPager` implementation.

In order to reproduce this you have to scroll down vigorously and while it's still happening try to scroll the list of items up - a sort of shaky stutter effect can be visible as if CoordinatorLayout was trying to scroll the view in separate direction than its child (`RecyclerView`).

You can view my layout here:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabControl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="500dp">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tabContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Just to provide some further details:

`headerContainer` contains `ConstraintLayout` with some stuff like bunch of textviews, button - pretty usual.

`tabContainer` contains `LinearLayout` with list of items (recyclerview)

Comment: is the recyclerView inside the `viewPager` ?

Comment: yes, inside `viewPager` there is LinearLayout with RecyclerView inside it

Comment: i have added my answer... try it..and tell if it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the recyclerView in the fragment of your ViewPager..

`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

> **This is happening because of the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` behavior of the viewpager..** this is causing the nestedScrolling.. that is why you feel the shaky effect..

Comment: The problem with this approach is then when I scroll down through the recyclerView inside `viewPager` and then try to scroll back up I'm not able to - I can only scroll to the top of the list

Comment: You can scroll both up and down?

Comment: Yes, but when scrolling back up I'm not able to reach the collapsed `headerContainer`

Comment: Basically enabling and disabling nestedScroll on recyclerView solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your RecyclerView

```
Recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: see my comment below @Santanu Sur answer